# Update parent component through Redux props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a comment section on my ticket detail view.  It's all working just fine actually.  I have a flag called comment Created and that is set to false on default.  Once the comment is created that is set to true.  I was trying to use that flag in the parent component.  I even mapped it to the state with map State To Props.

However, when I create the comment in the child component (actually child of the child component), the flag gets set to true, so that works, however, the parent of the parent component does not reload.  What I am doing now is just not using a full reload as a workaround.  The comments come back correctly that way, with the most updated comment.  I was just hoping for a different way of doing it that wouldn't require a full page render.

```
TicketDetail where I call the api

class TicketDetail extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        const id = this.props.match.params.id
        console.log(id)
        this.props.getTicket(id)
    }
    render(){
        const {ticket, ticketFetched, commentCreated} = this.props
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
        {ticketFetched  && <div><TicketDetailView ticket={ticket} user={this.props.user} commentCreated={commentCreated}/> </div> }
        </React.Fragment>      
         )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        ticket: state.tickets.ticket,
        user: state.users.user,
        ticketFetched: state.tickets.ticketFetched,
        commentCreated: state.tickets.commentCreated
    }
  }
  const mapStateToDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
    getTicket: (id) => dispatch(actions.getTicket(id)),
  })


  //For use with React Router and Material UI
  export default withRouter(compose(
    withStyles(styles, { name: 'TicketDetail' }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch)
  )(TicketDetail));
```

The view (dumb) container

```
import React from 'react'
import DateDisplay from '../usercontainers/DateDisplay'
import AssignTicket from '../ticketcomponents/AssignTicket'
import CommentList from '../ticketcomponents/CommentList'
import CreateComment from '../ticketcomponents/CreateComment'
export const TicketDetailView = (props) => {
    console.log('tdv')
    return (
        <div>


   <p>Subject:  {props.ticket.title}</p>
         <p>Description:  {props.ticket.body}</p>
          <p>Submitted By:  {props.ticket.created_by}</p>
         <p>Date Created:  <DateDisplay date={props.ticket.date} /></p>

              <AssignTicket ticket={props.ticket} user={props.user}> 
               </AssignTicket>
              <CommentList ticket={props.ticket} user={props.user} 
                commentCreated={props.commentCreated} />
             <CreateComment ticket={props.ticket} user={props.user}/>
            </div>
    )
}
export default TicketDetailView
```

Comment Create Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as actions from '../store/actions/ticketaction'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import TicketListView from '../ticketcontainers/TicketListView'
const styles = theme => ({})



class CreateComment extends React.Component {
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        const date = Date.now()
        const user = this.props.user.username
        const ticket = this.props.ticket.id
        this.props.postComment(e.target.comment.value, date, user, ticket)
        };

    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        let commentStatus = null
        if(this.props.commentCreated){
            commentStatus = (
                <p>Your comment added</p>
            )
        }
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {commentStatus}
            <textarea
            name='comment'></textarea>
            <button
            type='submit'>Submit 
            </button>
            </form>

        )
    }

}

const mapStateToDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
    postComment: (comment, date, user, ticket) => 
 dispatch(actions.postComment(comment, date, user, ticket)),
  })

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapStateToDispatch)(CreateComment))
```

Anything else I can do?

Comment: Can you upload TicketDetail?  I think you uploaded TicketDetailView twice by mistake.

Comment: Dang my b just a second

Comment: on TicketDetail's first render, does the console log CommentCreated: false, and then true on renders after the comment is created?

Comment: not on ticketdetails no, ticketdetail doesn't render at all again, i can try console.log(props) in the jsx and see how that goes

Comment: question: if you do 'console.log(props)' on your parent component render method, do you see the updated information there(even if the component did not reload)? like, you'd change stuff on the child component, then go back to the parent and see if the props were updated

Comment: They were not, not in the render method